# Integrate a function over a triangle in barycentric coordinate

Tags: integration, triangles, integral-domain, barycentric-coordinates

Let $A$ be the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$ and $(1,1)$ in $R^2$.
I want to find $$I=\int\limits_A (3x^3y-1)\mathrm{d}A.$$
My problem is that I would like to write the triangle in barycentric coordinate and integrate over the domain described in this way.
(the integral should result 1/10)
Any suggestion?